# Is it haram if i show my body like my hand or model to sell my product on my business?

Tags: halal-haram, business

Assalamualaikum ust/ustdz
so im a 15yo person,who wants start a business. Actually i wanna be dropshiper in online store, and i found photo card kpop which is cheap and i also asked to the seller if i can dropship her shop's product.
But Im afraid of Allah in the day of judgment idk i think if i sell  photo card KPop can be sin. Because it shows body of them. But can u give me an advice? Im so confused

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, to me, at least. You don't have to show ***your*** body, as from the title (Is it haram if i show my body), not unclothed. What is in the photo cards is a different thing.